# Pandas - resample a DataFrame by half-hourly frequency

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a `DataFrame`, `P`, that is divided into minutes - it looks like:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00  10088.245329   9905.462496  12328.830197
1900-01-01 00:01:00  10092.783624   9688.034026  11785.442316
1900-01-01 00:02:00  10312.043154   9501.677065  11784.126068
...
1900-01-01 23:58:00  15081.677177  12439.475801  15153.763812
1900-01-01 23:59:00  15311.646679  12028.347638  15155.108357
```

I'd like to resample this into half hourly sets. I can see that one can do this by hour:

```
P.resample('H')
```

Is there some, similarly easy, way I can get the same thing with half-hourly intervals?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this will be useful to others.

Comment: I didn't vote, but I suspect it's b/c you could have found the answer as you did without posting the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how:

```
P.resample('30min')
```

And [this](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timedeltas.html#resampling) is the relevant man page.